# Cannot create MYSQL primary keys

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to drop the existing primary keys and add two new primary primary keys in an existing database table using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `match_team_recruit` DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ind_stnum`, `team_send`);
```

However, I get the following error when running the query.

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '183-0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Please see attached Image below:
[image]

Can anyone advise how I can solve this?

Comment: You have at least two rows with the same values for `ind_stnum` and `team_send`. Find those, and decide if you need to change them, remove them, or rethink your unique.

Comment: 9 out of the 10 poeple who create a table make a id INT column with primary_key and auto_increment option.. I advice you to do the same here.. I don't get the feeling here the combination of the columns ind_stnum team_send is a good natural key to use here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you. Your advice has solved my problem

Comment: You have Duplicate key (`ind_stnum = 183` and `team_send = 0`). Remove duplicates and try again

Comment: @aynber, you are right. I do have same value for  `ind_stnum` and `team_send`

Comment: FWIW, your primary key allows nulls. This should be impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primary key in MySQL has to follow these three rules.

- A primary key must contain unique values. If the primary key consists of multiple columns, the combination of values in these columns must be unique.
- A primary key column cannot contain NULL values. It means that you have to declare the primary key column with the NOT NULL  attribute. If you don’t, MySQL will force the primary key column as NOT NULL  implicitly.
- A table has only one primary key.

Courtesy: [Introduction to MySQL primary key](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/)

To fix your problem you should just add one Primary Key to your table. 
 The Primary Key is used to distinguish Row's, therefor you can't have multiple Primary Key's in one table!